# tune2fs says "clean with errors". What next?

Tags: ext3, tune2fs

tune2fs says "clean with errors". What next?

We rebooted the server, but this did not help.

What is not the next most feasible step?

This is a production system. I would like to avoid down-times.

```
foo-host:~ # /sbin/tune2fs -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/111ce226-5f97-4fb7-b6cf-4b47f40236bd
tune2fs 1.42.11 (09-Jul-2014)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          111ce226-5f97-4fb7-b6cf-4b47f40236bd
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl

Filesystem state:         clean with errors  <<<======

Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              1310720
Block count:              5242880
Reserved block count:     262144
Free blocks:              3244098
Free inodes:              1195746
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      1022
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Fri Jul 31 18:24:44 2015
Last mount time:          Tue Nov  6 17:48:48 2018
Last write time:          Tue Nov  6 17:48:47 2018
Mount count:              7
Maximum mount count:      5
Last checked:             Fri Jan 19 21:57:47 2018
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          3380 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       786751
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      2898102d-4fb1-4758-b9ad-018ec4b2c92e
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

Answer (score 2):

Without downtime: Most likely not possible, as this appears to be your `/` volume.

Make sure you have a working backup, boot into a rescue system, try to fix with `fsck`. If not possible, restore from backup. You will find many guides how to use `fsck` with the help of Google (as usual...).